# Showing processed images from an IP camera

Tags: wpf, image, computer-vision, emgucv, ip-camera

I have an IP-camera that serves images. These images are then processed via [EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) and then I want to display the processed images.

To show the images, I use this code:

```
Window1(){
     ...
     this.Dispatcher.Hooks.DispatcherInactive 
         += new EventHandler(Hooks_DispatcherInactive);
}

Hooks_DispatcherInactive(...)
{
    Next()
}
```

Next() the calls calls the image processing methods and (should) display the image:

```
MatchResult? result = survey.Step();
if (result.HasValue)
{
    Bitmap bit = result.Value.image.Bitmap;
    ImageSource src = ConvertBitmap(bit);
    show.Source = src;
    ...
}
```

This works fine when I hook up a normal 30fps webcam. But, the IPCam's images take over a second to get here, also when I access them via a browser. So, in the mean time, WPF shows nothing, not even the previous image that was processed.

How can I get WPF to at least show the previous image?

Comment: Unfortunately, thats not under my control. It does jitter a lot though. The average is about 1000 milliseconds, but could just as well be 300 or 1700...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the image's buffer into a new BitmapSource image of the same format (PixelFormat, Height, Width, stride) using [Create (from Array)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms616045.aspx) or [Create (from IntPtr)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms616046.aspx) and display that BitmapSource in WPF's Image control,
or you can [use DirectX to do that faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105066/wpf-image-and-directx-surfaceformat) (for 30fps (and 1fps) the BitmapSource approach should do).

Also, consider NOT using events in the view, instead use bindings and commands.